# Point Cython to C source files

Tags: python, c, cython

I have a project mixing Python, Cython and C arranged like so:

```
root
    |- src
        |- foo
            foo.c
    |- name
        name.pxd
        name.pyx
    |- include
        |- foo
            foo.h
    setup.py
```

with very simple contents:

foo.h:

```
void add(int, double *, double *, double *);
```

foo.c:

```
#include "foo/foo.h"
void add(int N, double * A, double * B, double * C) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) C[i] = A[i]+B[i];
}
```

name.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "foo/foo.h":
    void add(int, double *, double *, double *)
```

name.pyx:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cpdef cython_add(np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] A, 
                 np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] B):
    cdef int N = min(A.shape[0], B.shape[0])
    cdef np.ndarray C = np.ndarray([N],dtype=np.double)
    add(N, <double*> A.data, <double*> B.data, <double*> C.data)
    return C
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("name/*.pyx", sources=["src/foo/foo.c"])
)
```

And compile with the following command:

```
CFLAGS="-I/path/to/root/include" python setup.py build_ext -i
```

Which compiles fine, except when I try `import name` in the python interpreter I get the following:

```
ImportError: dlopen(./name.so, 2): Symbol not found: _add
  Referenced from: ./name.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

which I assume means that even though everything compiled, Cython is not actually linking the right files together. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to change two things. I forgot to tell `name.pyx` to import `name.pxd`. So I had to add this line to the top of `name.pyx`:

```
from name cimport add
```

It also worked when I included `distutils` header information in `name.pyx` itself, so put these lines at the very top of `name.pyx`:

```
#distutils: language = c
#distutils: sources = src/foo/foo.c
```

And changed `setup.py` like so:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from numpy import get_include

extensions = [
  Extension("name", ["name/name.pyx"],
    include_dirs = ["include", get_include()])
]

setup(
  name = "name",
  ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
)
```